# Mandatory coupon before checkout in WooCommerce (optional: for specific products)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, coupon

I want to force the customer to add a coupon code before they can go to checkout. I would like it to work with every coupon code and every product in my WooCommerce store.

I am using this code and it is almost solving the problem, but it only works on a single coupon code (`freev1`)

How is it possible to make it work on every coupon code generated?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_coupon_code' );
function mandatory_coupon_code() {
    // HERE set your coupon code
    $mandatory_coupon = 'freev1';

    $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

    // If coupon is found we exit
    if( in_array( $mandatory_coupon, $applied_coupons ) ) return;

    // Not found: display an error notice
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Add coupon before checkout.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if `$applied_coupons` is empty, when empty add notice. Remove `$mandatory_coupon` & `if ( in_array...`

**So you get:**

```php
function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // Isset
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Get applied coupons
        $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

        // When empty
        if ( empty ( $applied_coupons ) ) {
            // Not found: display an error notice
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Add coupon before checkout.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );   
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10 );
```

---

**Update:**

To apply this for specific products in cart, use:

```php
function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // The targeted product ids
    $targeted_ids = array( 30, 815 );

    // Flag
    $found = false;
    
    // Isset
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Get applied coupons
        $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

        // When empty
        if ( empty ( $applied_coupons ) ) {
            // Loop through cart items
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                if ( array_intersect( $targeted_ids, array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $found ) {
        // Not found: display an error notice
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Add coupon before checkout.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10 );
```

---

**Additional question:**

> *"Will it be possible to use almost same code, but instead make it work from the checkout page and force the use of a coupon before
> placing a order?"*
>
> You could replace `woocommerce_check_cart_items` with the
> `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook for the checkout page